# Reducing the size of the publish menu in Expression Engine

Tags: menu, expressionengine

I am fairly new to ee.  I have a site built using it but it is not a conventional site.  There is only one page and all the content exists around that page, navigated with jquery scrolling.

I want to build a conventional site:

```
Page structure - 
           home
           about
           Services
                   Web design
                   Photography
                   graphic Design
           Portfolio
           Contact
```

What I want to avoid is having a massive list of channel fields in the publish drop down menu (as there is on my previous site)

How is it best to organise the channels?  I am trying to get my head around the pages module but I will still have loads of channel entries not organised.

I think having a channel called 'Pages' is the best start.  Then channel fields for each page.  Ok good....but I would need to create loads of field entries for each section of each page:

```
Pages ->
     Home 
     Home page featured image
     Home page left column
     home page right column
     About
     About featured image
     about main content
     Services featured image
     Services main content
     Web design featured image 
     Web Design main content
     Photography featured image
     Photography main content
```

But What I want is to have another two levels to the tree structure

```
Pages ->
     Home ->
             Home page featured image
             Home page left column
             home page right column
     About ->
             About featured image
             about main content
     Services ->         
             Services featured image
             Services main content
                      Web Design ->
                                   Web design featured image 
                                   Web Design main content
                      Photography ->
                                   Photography featured image
                                   Photography main content
```

Any suggestions or ideas? Am I just supposed to put up with having loads of channel fields, when I want to click on a page and have all the fields for that page come up together so that Home page featured image, Home page left column and home page right column are all edited at the same time from the same entry.

Comment: I think you mean "What I want to avoid is having a massive list of channels in the publish drop down menu". Correct?  You said "channel fields".

Comment: You know you can have field groups, right?  Each channel is associated with a single field group.  Field groups can be unique to a channel or shared among them.

Comment: right so instead of trying to align everything with a pages structure, I should be thinking about content types.

i.e featured image is one channel - containing the fields for home, about and other pages featured image.

wont thins be a little awkward for the user.  Imagine looking at the about page, spotting something to edit.  You will have to go to the back end and instead of looking for the about section, you are looking for the section that contains the thing you want to edit.  i.e looking for featured image or left column, then finding the entry for that page

Comment: EE (and other CMSes) wants you to shift your thinking from editing pages to editing data and presentation.  If it is a 5 page site, there may not be much of an advantage to the approach. But as you scale up in entries, templates and general complexity you gain a lot in modularity, flexibility and power.

Comment: yes, I did mean channels, not channel fields.

Yes, I have heard of field groups.  As i understand it:

Channels - contain field groups
Field Groups - contain fields

If on the home page I have a content slider, I want the images to be editable so I create a field group and associate it with a channel such as home.  I can then create another field group for the textual editable regions of the home page and associate this with the home channel?  then I would place exp channel home tag at top and bottom of home template.  And when editing in back end just search for the home channel in publish?

Comment: Right...

So do you think it is worth have an EE install for a small sight or rather use something like mojomotor?

I would worry that I wouldn't have enough flexibility to create dynamic navigation with sub menu in mojo.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand your question but I guessing you are having problems with structuring your navigation in the backend and frontend?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin this plugin allows you to re-structure the control panel menu to suit different user groups. So you can group your publish channel navigation how you want and reduce it down to any size. So you can call a navigation "edit home page" and have all the corresponding channels in the dropdown.

I also use this plugin to structure by navigation on the frontend http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/navee

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider the Structure add-on.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure